# How to query for alternative spellings and representations of words in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm using elasticsearch to query on the `theme` field in documents. For example:

```
[
  { theme: 'landcover' },
  { theme: 'land cover' },
  { theme: 'land-cover' },
  etc
]
```

I would like to specify a search of the term `landcover` that matches all these documents. How do I do this?

So far I've tried using the fuzziness operator in a `match` search, and also a fuzzy query. However neither of these approaches seems to work, which surprised me because my understanding of fuzzy searches is that they would provide a means of inexact matching.

What am I missing? From the docs I see that fuzziness definitely looks for close approximations to a search term:

> When querying text or keyword fields, fuzziness is interpreted as a Levenshtein Edit Distance — the number of one character changes that need to be made to one string to make it the same as another string.

I would consider 'landcover' and 'land cover' to be close. Is this not the case? (this is the first I have heard of Levenshtein Edit Distance so I don't know what extra/less characters mean in terms of this measurement).

An example of a match query that this doesn't seem to work:

```
{
  query: {
    match: {
      'theme': {
        query: 'landcover'
        fuzziness: 'AUTO' // I've tried 2, '2', 6, '6', etc.
      },
    },
  },
}

// When the term is 'land-cover' and fuzziness is auto, then 'land cover' is matched. But 'landcover' is not
```

And an example of a 'fuzzy' query that doesn't seem to work:

```
{
  query: {
    fuzzy: {
      'theme': {
        value: query,
        fuzziness: 'AUTO', // Tried other values
      },
    },
  },
}

// When the term is 'land-cover' and fuzziness is auto, then 'landcover' is matched. But 'land cover' is not. So works almost opposite to the match query in this regard
```

(NOTE - these queries are converted to JSON and do run and return sensible results, just the fuzziness doesn't seem to work as I would have expected)

Looking around StackOverflow, I see some questions that seem to indicate that querying an index is in some way related to how the index is created - i.e. that i cannot just run adhoc queries on any index that already exists and expect results. Is this correct? (sorry - I'm new to elasticsearch and I'm querying an index that already exists).

This answer seems related (how to find near matches for a search term): https://stackoverflow.com/a/55772800/3114742 - mentions that I should do something referred to as 'field mapping' prior to indexing data. but then the example query doesn't include the `fuzziness` operator. So in this case I'm confused as to what the point of the fuzziness operator is actually for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking more into the documentation I've found the following:

Elasticsearch uses the concept of an 'index' rather than a database. But from the perspective of someone familiar with CouchDB and MongoDB, which are both JSON stores, there is definitely some similarity between a CouchDB database and an Elasticsearch index. Although the elasticsearch index is not an authoritative data storage in itself (it's 'built' from a source of data).

For a given index called, for example, `my-index`. you can insert JSON strings (documents) into `my-index` by `PUT`ting to Elasticsearch:

```
PUT /... '{... json string ...}'
```

The JSON string can come directly from a JSON store (Mongo, Couch, etc.) or be cobbled together from a variety of sources. I guess.

Elasticsearch will process the document on insert and append to the inverted tree. For text fields this means K:V pairs will be created from JSON document text, with the keys being fragments of the text, and the values being references to where that text fragment is found in the source (the JSON document).

In other words, when inserting documents into an Elasticsearch index, the content is 'analyzed' to create K:V pairs that are added to the index.

I guess, then, that searching Elasticsearch means looking up search terms that are keys in the index, and comparing the values (the source of the key) to the source defined in the search (I think), and returning the source document where a search term is present for a particular field.

So:

1. Text is analyzed on insertion to an index
2. Queries are analyzed (using the same analyzer that was used to create the index)

So in my case (as mentioned above) the default analyzer is good enough to create indices that allow for basic fuzzy matching (i.e. in the match query, "land-cover" is matched to "land cover", and in the fuzzy query, "land-cover" is matched to "landcover" - I have no idea why these match differently!)

But to improve on the search results, I think I need to adjust the analyzer / tokenizer both when inserting documents into an index, and for when parsing queries to apply to an index.

My understanding of the analysis/tokenization is that this is the configuration by which inverted indexes are built from source documents. i.e. defining what the keys of the inverted index will be. As far as I can tell there is no magic in searching the index. search terms have to match keys in the inverted index otherwise there will be no results.

I'm still not sure what fuzziness is actually doing in this context.

So in short, querying elasticsearch seems to require a 'holistic perspective' over both how source data is indexed, and how queries are designed.

As a disclaimer,though, I'm not exactly an authoritative answer on this subject with less than one day of elasticsearch experience, so a better answer would still be appreciated!